# What am I missing in the following program?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};

int main() {
    int d;

    for (d = -1; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++)
        printf("%d\n", array[d + 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the for loop not run even once?

Comment: So, the best practice here is not to use #define statements in this way.

Comment: @Bobby - That is an opinion.  Not everybody would agree.

Comment: @Chris Lutz and @Heath Hunnicutt, so really, you all think this is a fine use of #define? I don't think it's a very radical "opinion." If you want to play that game please tell me a "best practice" which isn't "opinion."

Comment: Use `for (d = 0; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 1); d++) printf("%d\n", array[d]);` instead.

Comment: I agree with Bobby that using define statements in this manner is ugly, but don't really consider that to be the cause of hanifr's mistake.

Comment: @Bobby - Best practice that isn't opinion: Never use `gets()` as it can never be used safely.

Comment: @Bobby - Yes I definitely think not only is this a fine use of #define, this very macro is an extremely common use of #define.  Most people name it "dimensionof()", but it's the same macro.  How would you implement the same precise mechanism without a macro?   In C, not C++ -- I do realize there is a template solution.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt, isn't what you're talking about `#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))` rather than what was posted above? The original has the define depending on a variable name that is declared after the the #define is written.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is that `sizeof()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned.  Comparison of `-1` with `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2` should result in a warning indicating you have compared unsigned with signed.  When this comparison happens, the `-1` is converted to an unsigned value which is `MAX_UINT`.  On a 32-bit platform, both `-1` and `MAX_UINT` are `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Your `TOTAL_ELEMENTS()` macro could incorporate a cast to `(int)` but that isn't technically correct because `size_t` has a larger value range than `int`.  Best to change your loop variable so that it is declare as `size_t` and never becomes negative.

Comment: OK, I'll do it for you. Damn, where will I put MY upvote now? :)

Comment: Thank you both and Chris you and I crossed up-vote streams on this question as I also gave you one.  ;)  Good running into you here again.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing signed and unsigned arithmetic. sizeof yields a size_t (an unsigned type). When you do the `d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS -2)` the `d` gets converted to unsigned, and then compared. Since `-1` becomes the largest value in the target type when converted to unsigned, your condition becomes something like `0xffffffff <= 5`, which is always false so the loop never executes.

Answer (score 2):

Because `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is an unsigned value (type `size_t`) and `d` is a signed value (type `int`, which is most likely signed on your platform, and you're certainly assuming it is even if it isn't). The compiler in this case is converting `d` to an unsigned value, and converting -1 to an unsigned value usually results in `SIZE_MAX` or something similar, which is certainly greater than `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2`. To do this correctly, cast the unsigned value to a signed value: `(int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2)`.

Out of curiosity, why are you starting your index at -1 and then adding 1 to it in the loop? Why not just do this:

```
unsigned i;
for(i = 0; i < (TOTAL_ELEMENTS); i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

It would be much clearer than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS ((int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])))
```

assuming `array` will always be small enough. After all, you are using an integer to walk through the elements of the array.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure. Does sizeof do what you think it does here? It's been a while but I think you might be computing the size of an `int*` when you call `sizeof (array)`, which would be 1 (1 byte). Dividing that by the size of an int, which is usually 4 bytes, would certainly mean your loop never runs.

edit: it seems more likely that d is being converted to an unsigned type. The other posters may be correct.

Comment: No, this idiom (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) is very common.

Comment: -1: `sizeof(array)` does not return the size of a int* but the size of the full array and when you divide by `sizeof(array[0])` you divide with the size of one element. There is an issue only if `array` is a pointer (passed through a function or from data on the heap).

Comment: -1: Misinformation is worse than not answering at all (which implies you should delete your answer).

Comment: Thanks for being a human being Heath. To Brian: If my post is going to forever be tethered to this larger page containing better answers, and specifically to the comments on it which explain why it is false, why is it important for me to delete the answer? Don't be ridiculous.