# 3d array using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am new to C programming. Currently am trying to learn 3d array using pointers. Below is a program I am trying to debug. Can any one explain the difference between the two programs given below?

code1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int d[2][2][2] = {1, -2, -3, 0, -9, -1, 3, -1};
    printf("%d\n",*(*(*(d +1)+1)+1));
    if(*(*(*(d +1)+1)+1) <(a= sizeof( int )))
        puts(" u got it ");
    else
        puts (" but wrong");
    return 0;
}
```

code2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int d[2][2][2] = {1, -2, -3, 0, -9, -1, 3, -1};
    if(*(*(*(d +1)+1)+1) <(sizeof( int )))
        puts(" u got it ");
    else
        puts (" but wrong");
    return 0;
}
```

In the first code I am getting the *[…incomplete…]*

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683432 and certainly a duplicate (perhaps there is a better one, though). Look for integer promotion, `(size_t)-1` is `SIZE_MAX`, which isn't smaller than the size of an `int`. The assignment in the first snippet converts the `size_t` to an `int` so the left operand of `<` isn't promoted.

Comment: Huh?  I don't see `size_t` in this post, but I do see `sizeof(int)` which would probably be 4.

Comment: @david yes sizeof(int ) is 4.after assigning to a variable a ,what difference it make.What is the difference between the codes?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: The result of the `sizeof` operator is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Comment: `-1 < sizeof(int)` : results `sizeof` Since unsigned, -1 is compared by converting into unsigned. `-1 < (a=sizeof(int))` : results (a=sizeof(int)) Since signed(because type of `a` is `signed` int).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int d[2][2][2] = {1, -2, -3, 0, -9, -1, 3, -1};
> ```

The initializer is not fully braced but in this situation the initializers apply to the next element of the array in memory, so this assigns `d[0][0][0] = 1`, `d[0][0][1] = -2`, `d[0][1][0] = -3`, etc.

> ```
> printf("%d\n",*(*(*(d +1)+1)+1));
> ```

The thing full of stars is an obfuscated way of writing `d[1][1][1]` . The definition of `X[Y]` is `*(X+Y)` .

> ```
> (a= sizeof( int )))
> ```

The type of an assignment expression is the type of the left-hand operand. So the first program does  `(int)-1 < (int)4` . The second program does `(int)-1 < (size_t)4` . (assuming your ints are 4 bytes big).

In the first case this is `true`. In the second case it is a type mismatch. The type mismatch has to be fixed before the comparison can occur. The rules of C say that in this case the signed type is converted to the unsigned type, giving `(size_t)-1 < (size_t)4`. Since `(size_t)-1` is actually the largest possible `size_t` value, this comparison is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically an integer type comparison problem. First program compares a `signed int`(-1) with a `signed int`(a) and the second, a `signed int`(-1) with an `unsigned int`(sizeof()). Integer promotion happens in the second case, where `signed int`(-1) gets converted to `unsigned int`(-1) -> SIZE_MAX.
For more details on type comparison check the thread, [What are the general rules for comparing different data types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636793/what-are-the-general-rules-for-comparing-different-data-types-in-c)

Comment: +1, but I have some concerns.  The second program compares a (signed) `int` with a `size_t` (which is an unsigned integer type, but often not `unsigned int` — which is my main nitpick).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler rightly pointed, in the second case `signed int`(-1) is compared with `size_t`(-1). [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t) explains this better.

Comment: bracing the initializer may help understand better `int d[2][2][2] = { { {1, -2} , {-3, 0} }, { {-9, -1} , {3, -1} } };`